# Button not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code for the button (book button in my website) which is not working in Firefox but works other browsers. Is there anything that i can do to make it work in Firefox.I know that i can't use the anchor in my code, but i dont know how to get rid of it and make it work. I tried to do it and it didn't work.

This is my code;

```
$thisresult = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($booking_info['check_out'] <= date('Y-m-d')){
    echo    "<button style=' ' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>";
} 
else if(mysqli_num_rows($thisresult)>=1){
    echo "You have already booked this hotel!";
} 
else {
    echo "<button style=' ' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>"; 
}

}
```

i would appreciate a help,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not your down-voter and not a PHP or JavaScript expert, but have you researched the problem at all? If not, please do so before asking, and if so, please share the fruits of your researches in your question.

Comment: And please remove the profanity from your comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have tried to do it by myself and it didn't work. and what profanity?! i only said hell, didn't say any other swearing words... Its ridiculous, i posted this and got dislikes within the first 5 minutes. The guys who put them don't justify why, they just dislike the post. its silly

Comment: Please understand that this site is used by adults *and children*, and you've now just used profanity again when specifically asked not to, and so now you've gotten a down-vote from me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You for real? What on earth have i used there? adults can't see swear words as well? You know a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the above solution or if you want to stick with the links you have.
Instead of wrapping the (< a href="#">< / a >) with < button > tag
you can just **style**(using css) your (< a href="">) tag to look like a button

```css
.book-now-btn {
margin-top: 5px;
text-decoration:none; 
padding: 5px 10px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
background: #eeeeee; 
border-radius: 3px; 
color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>
<!-- using inline css -->
<a href="booknow.php?id=1" style="text-decoration:none; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #000000; background: #eeeeee; border-radius: 3px; color: #000000;"> Book now!</a>

<!-- using class -->
<a href="booknow.php?id=1" class="book-now-btn"> Book now!</a>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring everything else, you can wrap the button in a form tag to make it a "link", you could also add hidden fields for that "id" element if you want.

```html
<form style="display:inline" action="http://example.com/" method="get">
  <button>Button content</button>
</form>
```

Comment: would it be something like this according to my query; <form style="display:inline" action="'booknow.php?id=".$id." method="get">
  <button>Book now!</button>
</form>  ?